# Bathroom Faucet: Identification of Cartridge Replacement

Tags: bathroom, faucet

I have a very nice faucet that needs new cartridges but have been unable to find the manufacture of this unit to source out the correct replacement.

Does anyone here know how may have made this and where I might source these replacements?

Thanks

[image: Bathroom Faucet]

[image: Cartridge]

Answer (score 1):

Call community home supply in Chicago.  It’s a Fluhs 16 or 18 point ceramic cartridge.   I’m sure a Newport brass cartridge or something similar will be correct.   If not, they’ll be able to ID it from a picture.

Comment: Another good answer: thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the manufacturer.  =It is my experience that one can take the all parts to a nearby plumbing supply store (as opposed to Home Depot or Lowes etc...) and the counter people will be able to identify it and provide parts.

There is also an online stem finder tool with an option for unknown manufacturer:

https://www.danco.com/stem-finder/

Another approach I used successfully is to take a couple of photos from various angles of the cartirdge and of the set, then use google image search to find similar photos online. Scan through the results to find true matches. They may have been posted by a plumbing supply house or by a DIY blogger fixing theirs. Lastly if it is just the o-ring, replace the oring as a generic item.

Comment: NOt that easy.  I have been to Plumbing Mart, Noble Plumbing, Wolseley Plumbing...   non of these guys were able to help.   I'm at my wits end !

Comment: My faucet has a decorative imprint on the ceramic handle.  Does anyone know who made this and where I might locate replacement cartridges?

Comment: All good suggestions.  Yes, I have already searched google photos - zero hits.

Comment: All good suggestions.  Yes, I have already searched google photos - zero hits.  I have used the stem finder tool you recommend - zero results.  I would just replace the o-rings but the faucet has a small drip - so there may be a scratch on one of the ceramic disks...  and I would like to replace those too now that I have it all taken apart.  I have ordered a replacement set of parts (From China) should be here in a few weeks and I can see if that addresses my needs.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has this faucet it's called Liberty.

I did some research on my end.

Comment: Thanks for doing some research! Who manufactures "Liberty"? Also, could you include a link to the manufacturer or other pieces of research that pointed you in this direction? Those would be a excellent bits of info you could [edit] into your answer to make it more useful. Unfortunately, as it stands, this isn't particularly helpful.

Comment: No problem at all.  I'm not to sure who manufactured them but I managed to find out based some research . If you type in liberty faucet cartridge on google you can see Ferguson carries these cartridges